# Facebook API - Can't update adset targeting's geolocation by zip codes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to update my adset's targeting location to include 2 zip codes 85233 and 85224 but facebook keeps returning an Unknown error.

My request is

```js
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/[ADSET_ID]
targeting={ "geo_locations":{"zips":[{"key":"US:85233"},{"key":"US:85224"}]}}
access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

Response:

```js
{
     "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1,
      "fbtrace_id": "EA9s0p59E9h"
     }
    }
```

Please let me know the correct way to do this?

**UPDATE:** I have tried to update adset geolocation by lat and lng but the same error happened.

```
{  
   "geo_locations":{  
      "custom_locations":[  
         {  
            "radius":30,
            "latitude":30.1519297,
            "longitude":-97.8338758
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use "/v2.4/" and check whether it returns a proper response?
Because it seems like a FB API bug. Check this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/486654544831076/

Comment: they don't allow me to do this...fb api response with "(#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v2.10."

Comment: Well. In "/v2.4/" there was no such type of a bug.
And as you can see from the article above newer versions of this API produce this unknown error.

Comment: Did you try with v2.10?

Comment: I did and it returns the same response as v.2.11..is there any ways to test with v2.4 ?